# NPM project.json script section tasks are not executing correctly

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6

This is part of my project.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "babel-node buildScripts/startMsg.js",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel security-check open:src lint:watch",
    "open:src": "babel-node buildScripts/srcServer.js",
    "lint": "esw webpack.config.* src buildScripts --color",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "security-check": "nsp check",
    "localtunnel": "lt --port 3000",
    "share": "npm-run-all --parallel open:src localtunnel"
  }
```

When I run my tasks manually like:
**"nsp check" or "npm run lint -- --watch"** 
it works fine I see output in the console.

Problem is when I'm running my whole app **"npm start"** or **"npm run lint:watch"** these tasks are seems not running although I'm not getting any errors in the console and app seems to run fine I'm getting expected content.

What could be the problem here? and what is the difference if run nsp check or npm run security-check shouldn't the same thing happened?

Example when what shows my console when I execute these two above:
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTeEu.png)

Comment: When you run `nsp check` via your CLI, you are utilizing the globally installed version of _nsp_. When you run `npm run security-check`, _npm_ is utilizing the locally installed version of _nsp_ i.e. the version found inside your projects node_modules directory. It may be worth checking whether the versions of _nsp_ you have installed differ. You can verify which versions of _nsp_ are installed both locally and globally by: **1.** `cd` to your project directory and run `npm ls --depth 0 nsp` (for local version) **2)** Run `npm ls -g --depth 0 nsp`  (for global version).

Comment: @RobC I checked the versions and in fact they were different 2.6.2 and 3.2.1 global one. I changed local one to match global run it and it worked only for once also not sure why but lint:watch task started to working each time. Could there by some sort of a async issues?